# .htaccess redirect from subdomain to domain index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Seen a lot of similar questions but I'm still struggling with the right syntax.
I want to redirect any url like "www.en.example.org" OR "www.en.example.org/anypath"
to "www.example.org/index.php"

so in my subdomain root folder I added the following in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?en.example.org(.)*
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.org/index.php [R=301,L]
```

but only working for "www.en.example.org", if anything after this url, it does not work.
Any ideas are welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: sorry, I misread your question, seeing how you want to redirect everything to the same source you can just say

```
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.org/index.php [R=301,L]
```

without need for any RewriteCond statements

HTH, bovako

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick, I was (again) looking for something too complicated...